# What was Richie's big secret?

Tags: plot-explanation, it-chapter-two

In *It Chapter Two*, when Richie is going through the Derry alone, he visits the old arcade and the park with the Paul Bunyan statue.

When Pennywise appears, he starts teasing Richie saying that

> I know your secret, your dirty, little secret!

**What was this secret?**

The scene in the arcade might suggest that

> Richie is gay

but I find it a bit hard to believe since there was no other indication for that, other than willing to share a token to play  StreetFighter with another boy (who accused him rather to show-up in front of his cousin). Also in the book, Richie was divorced and was living a life of a celebrity, full of drugs and groupies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You guessed right.

The two big pieces of evidence is the token scene, which you noted, but also the very end of the movie where

> Richie carves R + E into the kissing bridge, which stands for Richie + Eddie.

You're also correct in that this is a significant deviation from the book.

Answer (score 5):

GGMG answered it pretty well but also there are official words about it. First, even in the novel, it was hinted [as per producer](https://in.ign.com/stephen-kings-it-chapter-2/139234/feature/it-chapter-two-how-richies-secret-comes-from-stephen-kings-book):

> Barbara Muschietti told IGN that there was one key Richie and Eddie moment from the book that stuck with her over the years: "The scene of Eddie's death, when Richie is saying goodbye, and caresses his cheek stuck with me for a good, what, 30 years. **The way I interpreted it was that there was love there.** I don't know if romantic, I don't know. But it feels totally natural that it would be unrequited love. To me, when Andy presented it as a possibility, it felt very natural."

But this time they didn't want to just hint it but show it to which was also the actor's demand:

> Bill Hader wanted the film to commit fully to making Richie gay or to not even bring it up. "Andy and I talked about how overt we should make it, and I said if it’s not overt, then why is he in the movie?," Hader told the New York Times. **"You can’t do a half measure on it. You’ve got to go the full way or don’t even allude to it. Let’s not be coy. Let’s just say what it is."**

Comment: I'm guessing the producer is also the sort of person who interprets Sam & Frodo's relationship as romantic.

Comment: @Thunderforge might be possible, let's see when they remake LotR